# Laravel with Vue and Passport

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios, laravel-passport

I have this project where I installed passport and vue with laravel. I have my auth endpoints but now I am struggling to get these endpoints to work with my front-end side of the project.

So when I installed Laravel I use the commend php artisan ui vue --auth to generate my login/register scaffolding.

The api endpoints are in the file api.php

This is part of my code from the AuthController.php:

```
    public function login(ApiLoginRequest $request){
    //debug
        //return $request;
    $credentials = $request->only(['email', 'password']);
    $authAttempt = auth()->attempt($credentials);
    if(!$authAttempt){
        return response([
            'error'   => 'Access forbidden',
            'message' => 'Please check your email and password'
        ], 403 );
    }
    //debug result needs to be true
        // return response([
        //     'debug response' => $authAttempt
        // ]);
    $http = new Client();
    $response = $http->post( 'http://laravel-xyzhub.test/oauth/token', [
        'form_params' => [
            'grant_type' => 'password',
            'client_id' => $this->CLIENT_ID,
            'client_secret' => $this->CLIENT_SECRET,
            'username' => $request->email,
            'password' => $request->password,
            'scope' => ''
        ]
    ]);
    return json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true );
}
```

Code for the vue template:

```
<template>

<div class="mx-aut h-full flex justify-center items-center bg-gray-800">
    <div class="w-96 bg-green-400 rounded-lg shadow-xl p-6" >

        <div class="text-center text-white uppercase">
            <h1 class="font-extrabold text-6xl">XYZ HUB</h1>

            <h1 class="text-3xl pt-8">Welcome Back</h1>
            <h2 class="pb-8 text-xs">Enter your credentials below</h2>
        </div>

        <!-- form -->
        <form class="pb-8" @submit.prevent="postNow" ref="LoginForm" method="post">

            <div class="relative">
                <label for="email" class="uppercase text-green-400 font-bold absolute pl-3 pt-2">Email</label>

                <div class="">
                    <input id="email" type="email" class="pt-8 w-full rounded p-3 text-green-700" name="email" v-model="credentials.email" autocomplete="email" autofocus placeholder="your@email.com">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="relative pt-6">
                <label for="password" class="uppercase text-green-400 font-bold absolute pl-3 pt-2">Password</label>

                <div class="">
                    <input id="password" type="password" class="pt-8 w-full rounded p-3 text-green-700" name="password" v-model="credentials.password" placeholder="password">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="pt-8">
                <button type="submit" class="uppercase font-bold rounded w-full bg-white text-green-400 py-2 px-3 text-2xl" v-on:click="loginUser">Login</button>
            </div>

            <div class="flex justify-center pt-8 text-white uppercase font-semibold text-sm">
                <a :href="recover"> Forget Password </a>
            </div>

            <div class="flex justify-center pt-2 text-white uppercase font-semibold text-sm">
                <a :href="register"> Register </a>
            </div>

        </form>

    </div>
</div>
```

```
<script>
export default {

    data(){
        return { 
            credentials:{
                email: '',
                password: ''
            }
        }
    },

    methods:{

        postNow(event){
            console.log("event" , {event , $form: this.$refs.LoginForm});

            axios.post('/api/login' , this.credentials)
            .then( response => {
                console.log ('response' , response.data); router.push("/register");
            })
            .catch( error => {
                console.log("error", error.response);
            })
        }
    } 

}
```

I know that my code in the template is not correct just not sure what I am doing wrong ... Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance

UPDATE:
So if I remove the prevent in the form and add a redirect once the response comes through then all of the sudden my submit does not go through

```
 <form class="pb-8" @submit.prevent="postNow" ref="LoginForm" method="post">
```

change it to

```
 <form class="pb-8" @submit="postNow" ref="LoginForm" method="post">
```

[image]

As you notice my endpoint is also not correct all of the sudden

Really confused with all of this ...

Comment: You are sending the `credentials` object to your `login` route, but don't seem to be using `credentials` in your Vue template?

Comment: @DelenaMalan mmm you are right. how do I use the credentials in my vue template (new to vue so I am learning as I go)...

Comment: In the `v-model` properties, you can use `credentials.email` and `credentials.password` instead of just `email` and `password`.

Comment: @DelenaMalan thanks. got it working. so stupid in the end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You noticed that endpoint is wrong.

So instead:

```
axios.post('/login' , this.credentials)
```

change to

```
axios.post('/api/login' , this.credentials)
```

Error is probably due to missing csrf token field in route "/login". 
With api routes, you don't need csrf.

Additional, it's easier to log erros response, example...

```
.catch( error => {
   console.log(error.response);
})
```